# Count how often in row the cell value increased by one

Tags: excel, vba

I have data like this and want to count for each cell (row C | the numbers) how often in that row the number of the cell increased by 1 or more. Is there a function or anything i can use?
[image]
kind regards

```
14122018    00:00:00    -0,307337687
14122018    00:00:01    -0,33286391
14122018    00:00:02    -0,313656444
14122018    00:00:03    -0,313656444
14122018    00:00:04    -0,3135594
14122018    00:00:05    -0,3135594
14122018    00:00:06    -0,3135594
14122018    00:00:07    -0,313656444
.
.
14122018    00:10:32     0,700890056
```

Answer (score 0):

Make a helper column, e.g. into col D with a formula like `=C2-C1>=1`  (starting at row 2).
Then, put the following formula into an empty cell: `=COUNTIF(D:D,TRUE)`

**Update**: Still not 100% clear. Try `=COUNTIF(C2:C$1000;">"&C1)` - is this what you need?

Comment: cant work because it only compares 2 rows each numbers getting bigger and smaller all the time

Comment: jeah i know but how should this work it only compares 2 row when i copy it down in the end its C160000-C159999>1

Comment: Sorry, I think I am confused about your requirement then. Maybe it would help if you show an example.

Comment: lets say i start with value in c9 than i want to know how many number from c10 to the end are increased by 1 ore more for that c9 value. and this number i want from every value so how man for c9 for c10 ...

Comment: i attached a picture where you can see the values in a chart.

Answer (score 0):

Let us suppose that you have 100 rows of data, starting on Row 2 (with a Header on Row 1, and ending on Row 101)

To count how many of these rows have data in Column B that increases from the cell above, you can use this formula:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--(B1:B100 <= (B2:B101 - 1)))
```

This will compare each cell to the one above.  Step-by-step, it first builds a list of comparisons like this to see if the second number is 1-or-more larger than the first:

> `(B1 <= (B2-1)), (B2 < (B3-1)), (B3 < (B4-1)) ... (B99 < (B100-1)), (B100 < (B101-1))`

Next, it converts those to `1` (True) or `0` (False), and then it adds all those numbers - this gives how many cells were larger than the cell directly above.

Comment: doesnt work with =SUMPRODUCT(--(C1:C160000 < C2:C160001))

Comment: @nowkin Are your values actually stored as numbers/times, or "Number Stored As Text"?  Try testing a smaller range (e.g. 10 rows), and inspecting it from "Formulas" > " Evaluate Formula"

Comment: jeah its real numbers not as text

Comment: and i also get a number but that number is not right
    -0,307337687283900
    -0,332863909870695
    -0,313656444074517
    -0,313656444074517
    -0,313559400134676
    -0,313559400134676
    -0,313559400134676
    -0,313656444074517
    -0,313656444074517
    -0,313656444074517
    -0,300890055708524
like for the first 11 lines with =SUMPRODUCT(--(C1:C10 < C2:C11)) i get 3 as result but there is not 1 time that value from first cell increased by 1 or more

Comment: @nowkin The code was originally just counting any increase - I have adjusted it to only count increases of 1 or more (i.e. subtract 1 from the "large" number, then do a `<=` comparison)

Comment: @nowkin If subtracting 1 is giving you a "wrong datatype" error, then you have non-numeric data in your column.